# in wordpress site facebook like button not working properly after using different url

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I am using wordpress for my site. Recently i changed the url of all my posts because the old url is quite long. But The old url has lot of facebook likes. So i am trying to use the old url for facebook likes count. I could do 80% of the job but getting stuck up in the last.

The new url of one of my posts is "http://www.leadershipandspirituality.com/servant-leadership-2/control-vs-influence-three-levels-of-leadership/"

To avoid confusion of urls: i will name them

url_new = http://www.leadershipandspirituality.com/servant-leadership-2/control-vs-influence-three-levels-of-leadership/

url_old = http://leadershipandspirituality.com/articles/articles-on-servant-leadership-by-radhanath-swami/servant-leader-or-both/

I am using redirector plugin to redirect "url_old" to "url_new"

So used the url_old in the code for facebook likes

```
  <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:65px; height:65px;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.leadershipandspirituality.com%2Farticles%2Farticles-on-servant-leadership-by-radhanath-swami%2Fcontrol-vs-influence-three-levels-of-leadership%2F&amp;layout=box_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=65&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=65"></iframe>
```

Now the page displays the likes counter according to the url_old. Till that i am successful

Now the problem part comes:

i loged into facebook and try to click on the like button. Then nothing happens. the like counter does not increase. But in one or two posts the like increased in the normal way but when i refreshed the page the likes became zero. So i feel like lost my likes.

Using the iframe code facebook generates the total likes count. So i dont have any control on how facebook is working.

Comment: You are setting your old URL as `og:url`, but it _redirects_ to the new one, and Facebook follows that redirect … and then under that new URL gets told again, that the `og:url` is the old one … [see debug tool output](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fleadershipandspirituality.com%2Farticles%2Farticles-on-servant-leadership-by-radhanath-swami%2Fservant-leader-or-both%2F). You will have to exclude the FB scraper from the redirect, and serve the Open Graph meta data from the old URL for this to work.

Comment: Ok. I changed the og:url to url_new. Please check it. What about the likes counter. I am using the old_url in it. But when i click the like its not increasing.

Comment: Likes are tied to _one_ URL. If you give your new URL as `og:url` now, of course all the “old” likes will not be included.